# Шифрование. ГОСТ 28147-89. bouncycastle, java

Tags: java, криптография

Нужно реализовать шифрование по госту, нашел пример и на его основе наваял следующее -

```
public class gost28147_89 {
        final private byte[] key;

        public gost28147_89(String keyString) {
            byte[] key = new byte[0];
            try {
                key = keyString.getBytes("UTF-8");
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                throw new ThrowFabric.ForbiddenException("Кодировка UTF-8 не поддерживается");
            }
            if(key.length == 32)
                this.key = key;
            else{
                this.key = null;
            }
        }

        public String encrypt(String data) {
            if(key.length != 32) return "";

            return encrypt(data, true);
        }

        public String encrypt(String data, Boolean isEncrypt) {
            if(key.length != 32) return "";

            String result;

            byte[] dataBytes;

            try {
                dataBytes = data.getBytes("UTF-8");
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                throw new ThrowFabric.ForbiddenException("Кодировка UTF-8 не поддерживается");
            }

            BufferedBlockCipher cipher = new BufferedBlockCipher(new GOST28147Engine());

            cipher.init(isEncrypt, new KeyParameter(key));
            byte[] dataoOutBytes = new byte[cipher.getOutputSize(dataBytes.length)];
            int len = cipher.processBytes(dataBytes, 0, dataBytes.length, dataoOutBytes, 0);

            try {
                cipher.doFinal(dataoOutBytes, len);
            } catch (InvalidCipherTextException e) {
                throw new ThrowFabric.ForbiddenException("Некорректный текст шифра");
            }

            result = Arrays.toString(dataoOutBytes);

            return result;
        }

        public String decrypt(String data){
            if(key.length != 32) return "";

            return encrypt(data, false);
        }
    }
```

`doFinal` вылетает с `data not block size aligned\norg.bouncycastle.crypto.BufferedBlockCipher.doFinal(Unknown Source)`
Кто нибудь работал с этой библиотекой? Не могу найти никакого описания как с ней работать...

**UPDATE**

Сделал по вашему примеру + подогнал блоки по размеру кратные 8. Шифрование/Дешифрование заработало, но выход после шифрования всегда на один блок(8 байт) больше входного массива.

```
byte[] dataBytes, tmpBytes;
        tmpBytes = data.getBytes();
        if(tmpBytes.length % 8 != 0){
            dataBytes = new byte[tmpBytes.length + (8 - tmpBytes.length % 8)];
            System.arraycopy(tmpBytes, 0, dataBytes, 0, tmpBytes.length);
        } else{
            dataBytes = tmpBytes;
        }
BlockCipher engine = new GOST28147Engine();
        BufferedBlockCipher cipher = new PaddedBufferedBlockCipher(new CBCBlockCipher(engine));

        cipher.init(isEncrypt, new KeyParameter(key1));
        byte[] cipherText = new byte[cipher.getOutputSize(dataBytes.length)];

        int outputLen = cipher.processBytes(dataBytes, 0, dataBytes.length, cipherText, 0);

        try {
            cipher.doFinal(cipherText, outputLen);
        } catch (InvalidCipherTextException e) {
            throw new ThrowFabric.BadRequestException(e.getMessage());
        }


        result = new String(cipherText);
        return result;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Любой блочный шифр (к каковым также и относится GOST 28147-89) умеет шифровать только 1 блок. Размер блока зависит от шифра, для GOST 28147-89 он равен 64 битам (8 байтам).

Алгоритм шифрования с применением блочного шифра обычно выглядит так:

1. Разбиваем исходный текст на блоки (в данном случае на блоки по 8 байт)
2. Если исходный текст не кратен 8 байтам, то проводим процедуру выравнивания блоков ([padding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padding_(cryptography))) - обычно PKCS#5 или PKCS#7
3. Далее выбирается алгоритм сцепления блоков - [cipher mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation) - обычно [CBC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Cipher_Block_Chaining_(CBC))
4. Далее собственно само шифрование, отдельно каждого блока сцепляя каждый блок с предыдущим выбранным способом сцепления (не забываем еще и про вектора инициализации, которые рандомизируют процесс шифрования)

Чтобы избежать всех этих сложностей придуман механизм простой инициализации, типа:

```
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("[Algorithm]/CBC/PKCS5Padding", <CryptoProvider>);
```

Который читается так: алгоритм `[Algorithm]`, мода сцепления `CBC`, алгоритм выравнивания `PKCS5`, правда для этого криптопровайдер должен соответствовать определенным требованиям. Судя по всему у вас провайдер Bouncy Castle, соответственно строка инициализации `Cipher` должна быть примерно такая:

```
Cipher cipher=Cipher.getInstance("GOST28147/CBC/PKCS5Padding", "BC");
```

Почитайте документацию Bouncy Castle или погуглите.

**Update**

Попробуйте так (аналог `GOST28147/CBC/PKCS5Padding`):

```
BlockCipher engine = new GOST28147Engine();
BufferedBlockCipher cipher = new PaddedBlockCipher(new CBCCipher(engine));

byte[] key = keyString.getBytes();
byte[] input = inputString.getBytes();

cipher.init(true, new KeyParameter(key));

byte[] cipherText = new byte[cipher.getOutputSize(input.length)];

int outputLen = cipher.processBytes(input, 0, input.length, cipherText, 0);
try
{
    cipher.doFinal(cipherText, outputLen);
}
catch (CryptoException ce)
{
    System.err.println(ce);
    System.exit(1);
}
```

Comment: где найти документацию? нашел несколько файлов здесь https://github.com/rodbate/bouncycastle-examples/tree/master/doc
но как то понятней не стало. К примеру Cipher вроде из javax.crypto как к этому объекту прицепить GOST28147Engine() из bouncycastle?

Comment: cipher1.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key) после простого механизма инициализации, я так понял нужно вызывать еще функцию инициализации в которую передавать ключ и режим - кодирование/декодирование. В примерах ключ генерируется, а если ключ нужно считать из сертификата или просто есть byte[32] как его инициализировать?

Comment: Попробовал ваш код  - last block incomplete in decryption\norg.bouncycastle.crypto.paddings.PaddedBufferedBlockCipher.doFinal(Unknown Source) Видно нужно подавать на вход массив байт кратный 8-ми?